# Building Android OS using Cygwin (Win7)

Tags: android, sdk, build, cygwin

I am trying to build the latest version of Android OS from source. I'm on Windows 7 x64, and am using Cygwin to do this. 
I get the following errors:

```
$ make -j8
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=3.1.4.1.5.9.2.6.5
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=windows
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
============================================
libpng: Ignoring gcc flag -fvisibility=hidden  on Cygwin
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/Program', needed by `out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-    check-timestamp'.  Stop.
```

It looks like it could be a path problem, maybe my Java path since this is in Program Files? My current path does not have any spaces.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use Cygwin, when Android has an excellent native Windows SDK?

Comment: Do you mean the AndroidNDK? I would like to build my own Android OS, so I thought I needed to build the AndroidSDK.

Comment: The SDK is used to build Android applications - you can't use it to build the actual OS. Do you mean that you're trying to build Android from source?

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not supported to build AOSP under cygwin, the particular error here looks unrelated to that. It looks to me like you've got it somewhere under c:\program files. If you put it in a path without a space it will likely at least go further than this.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html" shows you're not the only one who's seen this.

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/msg/453d69561bd00b30), it's a harmless warning. A response in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/browse_thread/thread/a981f553e9daa3e), by the same Android developer, seems to suggest a workaround to avoid the warning.

The first thread seems to be about building the SDK, rather than the OS itself. I'm not sure if it's equally harmless in building the OS.

Comment: Thank-you, I'm not as concerned about the warning messages, just that final error 'no rule to make target...'  Anyways, it looks like its not supported, as I found this on their page "To build the Android source files, you will need to use Linux or Mac OS. Building under Windows is not currently supported." Too bad! :(

Comment: @lost_bits1110: D'oh! Sorry, I missed that last bit in the output you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build Android OS on Windows. The can do this only using Linux or Mac, because there  are some tools absent in Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is case insesitive, some files will appear as duplicate to Windows.
This will prevent you from building a Android system